# select size with jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget

I use this widget http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget.

My problem is that I can't define the size of my select like this:

```
<select size="10">
</select>
```

I think I have understand the method, it transform a html 'select' tag into a html 'button' tag that show a hidden div when you click on this button.

I try to delete every 'display:none' in the css, in order to see the div without click on the button but there are no results..

EDIT:
it seems that display:none come directly from jquery.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is not to remove the `display: none` what you need to do is change it to `display: block`

Comment: you're right, I had only try on css files but it is in jquery.js.. thanks.